# Going wrong in SQL join

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table called `tbl_users`

```
================================================================================
system_name | user_id | username | password | system_id | group_id | user_level
================================================================================
Demo        | 12345   | demo     | demo     | 99999     | 54321    | Admin
================================================================================
Demo        | 78794   | demo2    | demo2    | 99999     |          | Employee
================================================================================
```

And second table as `tbl_groups`

```
=================================
system_id | group_id | group_name
=================================
99999     | 54321    | engine     
=================================
```

Am using this query :

```
SELECT username, user_level, system_name, tbl_users.system_id, tbl_users.user_id, tbl_users.group_id, group_name 
FROM tbl_users JOIN tbl_groups 
WHERE tbl_users.group_id = tbl_groups.group_id 
AND system_name = 'demo' 
AND tbl_users.system_id = '99999'
```

But using the above query am just getting a row of `Demo User`, I want Demo 2 also but can't get it done, If am removing `tbl_users.group_id = tbl_groups.group_id` I get both rows but in `group_name` it's printed **engine** in `Demo2 User` `group_name` column which is wrong as he has no group currently, so how can I query that I get all users and names of groups if a user is in or else I want group_name column blank if user is in no group.

Comment: Could you post your expected results output? You'd definitely get an answer with that.

Comment: you are using system_name='demo' then how are you getting demo2 also??

Comment: @Sanuj both are in `demo` system and (Adrian) sorry but this is really tought to pick out of my code as this query is in PHP and am using Session values as values in my query so I made a separate demo to show you people

Comment: @Adrian right now if I am using the current query than I just get a single row in which `group id` is there in `tbl_users` of user `demo` but if I remove this line `tbl_users.group_id = tbl_groups.group_id ` which is foreign/primary to connect both tables than I get both users in result but I get `group_name` as `engine` in both users where I should only get `engine` as `group_name` in demo user and not in demo2 user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for an [OUTER JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join):

```
FROM tbl_users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_groups 
  ON tbl_users.group_id = tbl_groups.group_id
WHERE ...
```

Comment: you **ROCK**, gosh I need to revise my SQL concepts soon, I tried Left, right joins everything, but I wanted was this thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you want it return all rows in the left table, use LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN.
Also, you should use `ON` instead of `WHERE` when specifying `JOIN` criteria.

```
SELECT username, user_level, system_name, tbl_users.system_id, tbl_users.user_id, tbl_users.group_id, group_name
FROM tbl_users LEFT JOIN tbl_groups
ON tbl_users.group_id = tbl_groups.group_id
```